# add counters to the URL

Tags: php, mysql, counter

I want to add counters to the URL, when it is displayed.

```
    http://domain.com/downloads/123456789?click=text
```

**text= ref*

*PHP & MySql*

Detail pic: http://img17.imageshack.us/img17/5233/downloadclick.png

how can i do? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
$click = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['click']);

mysql_query ("insert into table (field1, field2, field3) values (1, 2, '".$click."');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answer,"Header" I added but the page was white.


       `<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "----", "----") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";

$click = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['click']);

mysql_query ("insert into table (field1, field2, field3) values (1, 2, '".$click."');
?>`

Comment: You didn't literally put that in your script, right? You have to alter the query to match your table structure. For the white page, enable [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: (1): http://img402.imageshack.us/img402/2016/errorclick.jpg

(2): http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/264/sqltablo.jpg

Unfortunately, no error_log

Comment: I don't see you enabling error reporting. Click the link I posted. I expect people I help to try something for theirself too. Edit the SQL statement to match your table structure. If you don't know how, please go see some SQL tutorials.

Comment: I think i can not .. Again thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0):

If your table structure is like :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `clic` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `text` (`clic`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

You can use :

```
// connect to mysql server
mysql_connect ('localhost', 'user', 'password') or die('connexion failed');
// select the database
mysql_select_db ( 'thedatabase' ) or die('db select failed');
// update the value
$res = mysql_query('UPDATE `table` SET count=count+1  WHERE clic="yep" ') or die(mysql_error());
```

But, the row must exists before.

Also your table structure should avec the searched col to be indexed for performance issus. ( UNIQUE KEY `text` (`text`) ).

Comment: Thank you for answer, What is the URL query? Database not updating.

Comment: Answer updated. | the url was http://whatever.com/the_url.php?clic=something. Is there a row with clic="yep" in your database ?

Comment: Please check 7seb; http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/460/downloadclick2.png

Comment: I think it's not good to change the question while you get answers. You better post a new question. Later readers won't understand anything.

Comment: Okey, thank you so much for interst.

Comment: You really shouldn't draw pictures (not in the first place since imageshack might delete the files so future readers don't understand a thing of this) but try to type it in reasonably understandable English. I know it's hard if it isn't your native tongue as is it for me, but it really helps other people understand your problem.

Comment: English is not very adequate. This is why i paint.
I use a "CMS" and "download manager" script.

Download manager file-link: domain.com/downloads/1234

CMS I want to learn which of my members had downloaded the above file.
Therefore, I add the name of the download URL of the end members.